# Wait for Controller Action to be Called in MVC Method

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to execute a remote process using C# in ASP.Net MVC which will POST data back to one of my controllers. Is there a way to wrap this controller action in an event within my calling method so I can wait for the POST data? I am not sure what options I have, if any. I am hoping for something like:

Calling Method:

```
public void MainMethod()
{ 
    ExecuteRemoteProcess();
    //Listen for PostData();
}
```

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public string PostData()
{
    var length = Request.ContentLength;
    Stream req = Request.InputStream;
    req.Seek(0, System.IO.SeekOrigin.Begin);
    string json = new StreamReader(req).ReadToEnd();
    return json;
}
```

**Edit:**
MainMethod is a separate class method within the MVC app that would simply call an external process. The external process would do its thing and then httppost some data back to the MVC application using the PostData() controller action.. but ultimately I need the data back in my MainMethod() thread since it is orchestrating many of these smaller external processes.

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking here.  Can you provide a bit more context?

Comment: Presumably `ExecuteRemoteProcess()` will call the controller via HttpClient or WCF channel, correct? So you just need to wait for the call to complete and the json to be returned. Once it has returned you can be assured that the `PostData()` action has completed and therefore the data have been posted. I don't understand what you want in addition to that.

Comment: If you are calling API from your code,  you can simply grab the result.

Comment: I want to execute a remote process (SSIS) and have the process post back some data to my MVC application. I can easily execute the SSIS process and have the process POST data to the MVC application, but at that point I have two separate threads. My question is if I can capture the controller action from within the method that called the remote process.

Comment: I'm confused by the question - is the MainMethod supposed to be called from PostData with the json?  Is MainMethod on another class, or rather, why can't you call MainMethod from PostData in the code?

Answer (score 1):

You need to do the processing of the posted results in the `PostData` action, not in `MainMethod`.  That's the request that's being made when you want to do your work, so that's the action that you need to write the code to handle it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are wanting your method to wait until the process is finish to then continue. Make the method asynchronous.

```
public async Task<string> PostData()
{
    //Put 'await' infront of the call
}
```

Comment: So I considered async but I don't think this applies to my problem. I am wanting MainMethod() to be notified when PostData() is called by an external process. MainMethod() won't be calling PostData() directly